# Circumvent ld lookup

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, ld, search-path

Having installed my toolchain in a different directory than requested by its vendor, I've been running in some smaller issues easily solved by setting the COMPILER_PATH, C_INCLUDE_PATH, CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH variables appropriately.

However, there is one issue which I can’t seem to dodge so easily:

```
beo-it@bsrv01:/tmp/async$ xscale-linux-g++ -fPIC -DBOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_EPOLL -I/var/lib/c++/boost/boost_1_48_0/target/arm-linux-4.4.2/include -oasync main.cpp -L/var/lib/c++/boost/boost_1_48_0/target/arm-linux-4.4.2/lib/static -pthread -lboost_system -lboost_thread
/var/toolchains/arm-linux/4.4.2/arm-linux-4.4.2/arm-linux/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/local/arm-linux-4.4.2/lib/be/libpthread.so.0
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am unsure as to why `ld` would be looking for a library by an absolute path, but that’s exactly what seems to be the case here. Is there any way to circumvent this behavior and provide it with the correct path of the shared library?

Comment: Did you check your `ldconfig` setup? Perhaps it was there and is still stuck in the cache. Refer to `man ldconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think is to put a symlink where it actually looks but point it to the right file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, that’s of course exactly what I wanted to avoid here. I installed the toolchain in a different directory because some of my toolchains would by default allocate the same path. In order to have them installed on the same system, I need them in different directories and can’t use symlinks for either of them.